# Create persistent array in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, associative-array

I want an associative array in my bashrc file and I want to add to or delete from it whenever needed, but if I put the array declaration in the bashrc file it will get redeclared every time bash is run and so the previous values will be lost. What should I do?

Comment: You can set the array conditionally... Check if the variable is already set! Use `[ -z ${var+x} ]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any nice way to do that. You'll have to do the de/serialization, saving and restoring by hand. Example code:

```
save_array(){
        declare -n a=$1
        for i in "${!a[@]}"; do printf '%s\0%s\0' "$i" "${a[$i]}"; done
}
restore_array(){
        unset $1; declare -gA $1
        declare -n a=$1; local k v
        while read -d '' k && read -d '' v; do a[$k]=$v; done
}
```

Or a simpler variant, which takes advantage of the format of `declare -p`[1]:

```
save_array(){ declare -p $1; }
restore_array(){ local l; read -r l; eval "${l/-A*=(/-gA $1=(}"; }
```

Then:

```
$ declare -A a1; a1[foo]=bar; a1[baz]=qux

$ save_array a1 >/tmp/save
$ restore_array a2 </tmp/save

$ echo "${!a2[@]} // ${a2[@]}"
baz foo // qux bar
```

The `readarray`/`mapfile` built-in doesn't seem to support associative arrays, nor using NUL bytes as delimiters. Also, `bash` doesn't seem able to tie an array to a database, as `perl` can with `tie %hash, 'DB_File', $filename, ...`.

[1] depending on your usage, you can make it even simpler:

```
#! /bin/bash
trap 'declare -p a1 a2 > ./path/to/saved_arrays' EXIT
. ./path/to/saved_arrays 2>/dev/null || declare -A a1 a2

a1[$1]=$2
a2[$2]=$1
```

Comment: this is a really cool way, thanks.

Comment: I've hit on a much better idea, see the updated answer.

Comment: I'm just learning these commands, but it's strange "EXIT" was not in the "man 7 signal" and was in the "man trap" instead. The second way sounds amazing. "delcare -p array" is interesting. BTW, what's this doing `2>/dev/null` in the second solution?

Comment: Oh Google found that easily and I read what it does. thanks again.